Flutter - How to change state of child widget when parent state is changed?
I'm new to Flutter and I've been trying to create a simple utility in my app with a few input fields that are disabled until the "Edit" button is clicked. Once it is clicked all the fields become editable.
When the "Edit" button is clicked it shows additional widgets. There is an "Add" button that adds the device widget (child) to the parent widget.
I'm updating the value of the _isEditing variable on the click of the Edit button but it is not changing the state of the child variable which I'm passing through the constructor. I'm having a hard time understanding this. Please help me out, how can I update the state of the child class as well?
Here, is the code for the Parent class
class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  const Parent({super.key, required this.index});

  @override
  State<Parent> createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<ParentBox> {
  bool _isEditing = false;
  List _devices = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _devices.add(Child(isEditing: _isEditing, index: 0));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                formField(
                  "Location:",
                  TextEditingController(),
                  hint: "Enter location",
                  small: true,
                  required: false,
                  labelSize: 16,
                  disabled: !_isEditing
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                ..._devices,
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                _isEditing
                  ? Align(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                        child: generalButton("+ Add", onPressed: (){
                          setState(() {
                            _devices.add(Child(isEditing: _isEditing, index: _devices.length - 1));
                          });
                        }),
                      )
                    )
                  : Container(),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        showAlertDialog(
                          context,
                          "Alert",
                          "Alert text"
                          onYesPressed: () {
                            
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.delete_outline_rounded,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                    _isEditing
                      ? generalButton("Save", onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _isEditing = !_isEditing;
                          });
                        })
                      : generalButton("Edit", onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _isEditing = !_isEditing;

                          });
                        })
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here is the code for the child class
class Child extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isEditing;
  final int index;
  const Child({super.key, required this.isEditing, required this.index});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
          child: formField(
            "Device:",
            TextEditingController(),
            small: true,
            required: false,
            labelSize: 16,
            disabled: !isEditing
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
          child: formField(
            "Expiration Date:",
            TextEditingController(),
            small: true,
            required: false,
            labelSize: 16,
            disabled: !isEditing
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!
UPDATE
I have added the pictures of what I'm trying to achieve.
Non-Edit Mode

Edit Mode

When I click on the Edit button, I want to change all the fields to be editable. The add button adds another row of the device row that is created as a child. When Save button is clicked, all the fields should go back to being non editable.

Convert child widget to stateful widget. Use didUpdateWidget in child widget. This method is called whenever the widget parent changes. It also give you oldWidget in it. Which you can use to compare previous and current state of data received from parent. You can call setstate() here to updated child widget state.

And why the editable flag is not working because you defined it's scope inside init. So widget is already prebuild. Even you update the flag it will not affect the prebuild widget. My advice use listview.builder rather then predefined list of widget. And pass the flag in it. So everytime you call setstate the listview will build together with its children. And if the item are in large no. It will also make it scrollable.

I'm trying to understand, but here's what i think it's your wanted behavior:
You have a list of Widgets : List<Child> which mainly encapsulates isEditable flag in each of its elements.
And you are trying to update an instance variable of the parent class:
  bool _isEditing = false; 

_isEditing = !_isEditing; // in your setState

Ok, after doing the above guess what: The devices list still the same
You need to change each element's isEditing value manually.
  devices.forEach((child){
    
    child.isEditing =  _isEditing;
  }); 

it's ok to change them within setState(), but Be careful because the Child class doesn't provide a setter for isEditing variable you are marking it as final.
remove that final, so it become mutable.
Hope it helps you.

Thank you! This does update the editability of the fields but it doesn't do so on clicking the buttons. I have to tap outside of the field on any other item and then it changes the state. Not sure why is that.
